# Respond with message while generating files

Tags: api, go, concurrency, file-generation, waitgroup

I have a service where users can export data to an excel file I generate for them on my backend server. Sometimes these exports can be large. So as a way to keep UX in mind, I want to confirm that the server received the request and responds that the documents are being generated and will be emailed to them after its complete.

This is a bare bones example of what I have so far.

Code:

```golang
func generateDocx(n int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        amt := time.Duration(rand.Intn(250))
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * amt)
        fmt.Println("Export: ", n, "Document number:", i)
    }
}

func ExportService() {

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go generateDocx(i, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
// email user after all documents are generated
    fmt.Println("Sending email that documents are ready")
}


func main() {
    
    finish := make(chan bool)
    // var input string
    // fmt.Scanln(&input)
    
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    
    type Reply struct {
        Title   string
        Message string
    }

    router.HandleFunc("/export", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
        fmt.Println("starting generation")
        ExportService()
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&Reply{
            Title:   "Generating",
            Message: "Your files are being generated, you will recieve an email when the files are ready.",
        })
        fmt.Println("responded")
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
    <-finish
}
```

When endpoint is hit:

```golang
starting generation
Export:  8 Document number: 0
Export:  6 Document number: 0
Export:  9 Document number: 0
Export:  6 Document number: 1
Export:  4 Document number: 0
Export:  3 Document number: 0
Export:  2 Document number: 0
Export:  1 Document number: 0
Export:  3 Document number: 1
Export:  0 Document number: 0
Export:  6 Document number: 2
ect...
Sending email that documents are ready
responded
```

Even while the waitgroup is in ExportService and does not return anything back to the handler, the response still waits for the generation to complete before responding with the success message.

I want to say I understand concurrency in Go but I am obviously missing something. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Ok why does that work? I removed the wait group and I am getting the behavior I want. Which is `starting generation => responded => Exporting docs... => send email`.

Comment: So the `ExportService` starts the goroutines but does not stop them? The reason I had the waitGroup was so it didnt stop the goroutines

Comment: Run the export service in a goroutine: `go ExportService()`.

Comment: If your service is restarted, in flight requests will be lost, and the user will be expecting an email that never comes.  If that's not a big concern fro you, `go ExportService()` should work.  `ExportService` *would* wait for its waitgroup, but your request handler wouldn't wait for `ExportService`.

Comment: Thats exactly the behavior I want to happen,  is the user to receive the email, do you think there is a better way to go about doing this?